# How to add Jameel Noori Nastaleeq fonts in TCPDF?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, fonts, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF library with CodeIgniter. How can I add Jameel Noori Nastaleeq fonts?

I have added **Jameel_Noori_Nastaleeq.ttf** font file under **tcpdf\fonts** folder, and included it like:

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/fonts/Jameel_Noori_Nastaleeq.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont('Jameel Noori Nastaleeq', 'BI', 20, '', 'false');
```

But it is not working. Anyone have an idea, how to include it?

Comment: "It's not working" - Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

I have applied jameel noori nastaleq font in my android studio app, it's working fine. I tried in this way:

1. set the name of the file without underscore(_) or dashes (-) with all small letters
2. don't use .ttf while giving a path of the font.
3. use this directory drawable/font

Hope this will help you.

Comment: was not working without .ttf, when added extension by renaming font type font/jameelnoorinastaleeq.tff, it started working like a charm, anyhow thanks, solved my issue, searched many times for adding this font type, but found today :)
Android Studio Version 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in path of your font. You must add font with full path. like

```
/home/username/public_html/...
```

try to upload your font in root path and locate it with this format.

```
/home/username/public_html/Jameel_Noori_Nastaleeq.ttf
```

Comment: I did it, but nothing happened. The font path is correct. I cross-check it.

Comment: @ShehrozAltaf maybe your file is broken. so change with another standard font to check other things is correct or not

Comment: I am using the same file to display URDU on the web browser, and it is working fine on the browser.

Comment: @ShehrozAltaf so it seems to this font file is broken. try redownload and check it.

Comment: yeah, I did. I downloaded Jameel_Noori_Nastaleeq.ttf from different origins, but result is same.

Comment: @ShehrozAltaf i think because it font is nastaleeq. It is symbol and you must set 4th parameter to `4` not `32`. flag 4 is for symbols

Answer (score 0):

Is better if you convert the font to ctg.z/z/php files. You can convert ttf fonts with http://fonts.palettize.me and then put uncompressed result in fonts folder into tcpdf class.
Then you can add it with $pdf->SetFont('jameelnoorinastaleeq', 'BI', 20);